# How can I create new attribute based on img src and use original src value for another?

Tags: jquery

I want to use Lazy Load which requires an attribute named "data-original" which points to the original image src value.  I can create the new "data-original" with the value from the src attr like this without a problem:

```
  $('img.lazy').each(function() {
    a =  $(this).attr("src");
        $(this).attr("data-original", a);
   });
```

But, if I follow with this (which Lazy Load needs the src value to be):

```
  $('img.lazy').each(function() {
    b =  "img/grey.gif";
        $(this).attr("src", b);
   });
```

The data-original and src atrr both become "img/grey.gif"

Thanks from the newbie!

Comment: Are you using a plugin for this? And if so, does they both become `img/grey.gif` even if that plugin is disabled?

Comment: Yes, the Lazy Load plug-in is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You could put both in the same loop. And even thought this is probably not a problem here, you should normally use "var a = ..." if you are not using a global variable called a.

```
$('img.lazy').each(function() {
   $(this).attr("data-original", $(this).attr("src"));
   $(this).attr("src", "img/grey.gif");
});
```

Comment: could it be that your function somehow gets called twice?

Comment: Have checked that, will check again.

Answer (score 1):

Changing some attributes of DOM elements are not permitted by some (or maybe all?) browsers -for security reasons- using the jQuery `.attr()` method. If that is the case you can use the following approach.

```
$('img.lazy').each(function() {
    $(this).attr("data-original",$(this).attr("src"));
    $(this)[0].src = "img/grey.gif";
    // or $(this).get(0).src = "img/grey.gif";
});
```

**[EDIT]**

Switched the order:

```
$('img.lazy').each(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    // assign the initial src value to temp var
    $(this)[0].src = "img/grey.gif";
    // or $(this).get(0).src = "img/grey.gif";
    $(this).attr("data-original",src);
});
```

I'm not familiar with Lazy Load. There's a chance that it might be replacing the elements instead of changing their attribute values. If that is the case then you will need to take a different path.

**[END EDIT]**

I'm not sure if that's your issue here, though.

Comment: Thanks! Nope, same results, both attr get same value of "img/grey.gif". Tried in Chrome and FF.

Comment: So can the issue be summarized as Lazy Load replicating the src attribute (to the data-original attribute) when it gets changed?

Comment: Also, you may want to change the order to make sure by changing the src value as the first step and then setting the data-original value to what it should be.

Comment: How can I change the src value first when I need it to set the data-original value?

Comment: Thanks, will try that. Meanwhile, I'm modifying the code that produces the html output before it gets there to solve the problem. More trouble but seems to work.